# Get points from a kml LineString

Tags: kml, fastkml

I have a KML file with a LineString. I'm trying to load the points in Python. I'd like to use the FastKml library, but am open to other solutions. FastKml has one example for reading KML, but I have not been able to convert that to get the LineString points.

Comment: Do you have a sample file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the file with OGR and access the points from the layer:

```
from osgeo import ogr

ds = ogr.Open('KML_samples.kml')

for lyr in ds:
    for feat in lyr:
        geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
        if geom != None:
            for i in range(0, geom.GetPointCount()):
                print (geom.GetPoint(i))
```

Comment: I did not know that ogr could access kml files, really good to know! However when I run this script on a .kml file with both `LineString` and `Points` it only returns the coordinates of point features (and only some of them...) and not coordinates of points in the 'LineString'

Comment: Do you have a sample file? Otherwise it is difficult to reproduce what you wrote.

Comment: I used the exact code you have above. For the file I posted here it just prints out 3 points, which are all cointained in a `<Placemark>` tag in the file. [Here is the link of the sample google developers kml file I used](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml)

Comment: Thanks for posting the sample file. Your file has several layers. I edited the code. Now it loops over all the layers in your file. In addition it has one feature with no geometry (which is weird). I added an if statement to catch that.

Answer (score 1):

kml is a xml language focused on geographic visualization, with attention to annotation of maps/images and the navigation of them. For this reason a python script utilizing an xml parser such as `xml.etree.ElementTree` should be able to extract the coordinates in a fairly straightforward manner.

Understanding that for line strings they are identified by the `<LineString></LineString>` tag. Within the `<LineString>` tag is the `<coordinates>...</cordinates>` tag that contains the list of coordinates.

Here is an example below of how to extract the coordinates for all LineStrings in a .kml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
filePath = r'C:\yourFile.kml'
tree = ET.parse(filePath) 
lineStrings = tree.findall('.//{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}LineString')

for attributes in lineStrings:
    for subAttribute in attributes:
        if subAttribute.tag == '{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}coordinates':
            print subAttribute.tag, subAttribute.text
```

This method can be used to extract the coordinates of other named tags in a .kml file, containing the `coordinates` tag. The key is knowing the namespace that your kml file is using in my case it is {http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}. But that info can also be accessed once you have created a tree via the following code:

```
root = tree.getroot()
```

`root.tag` then contains the namespace for the version of kml you are using.

[See Google Developers guide on LineStrings here](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#linestring) for more info on the syntax of the `<LineString>` tag

Comment: KML isn't really "modified .html". Perhaps you wanted to say it is just a form of XML?

Comment: Yes I can parse this with pure Python and regex, or shell and regex, etc. But there are several Python libraries that are **built for KML**, so I am trying to use them. It ought to be a fraction of LOC, especially if there are multiple named LineStrings in one KML.

Comment: Understood. I was just going off of your question. You said you have a kml with _a LineString_ and you did not mention other libraries but simply _solutions_.

Comment: Thanks BradHards. I have modified the post to show the correction.

Comment: +1 JamesSLC. KML is XML, so XML libraries like xml.etree are the way to go. I've written some KML helpers for xml.etree in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keytree/.

Comment: Thanks sgillies, looks like a great project! Thanks for the support, good to see solid programming applied to GIS purposes

Answer (score 1):

In fastkml, the process that I have found is this :

- Read KML File
- Parse Placemarks from the file
- Parse Geometries (if any) inside the Placemarks
- If LineString, extract coordinates

Since you didn't mention where exactly you get stuck on in this process, I think this article can help you out throughout the process : https://medium.com/@wwaryan/the-definite-only-guide-to-fastkml-58b8e19b8454